# Replace UITableViewCell text with UITextView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uitextview

In my App i'm setting an UITextView as contentView of an UITableViewCell so you can write into it. This is how I set it:

```
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x, cell.bounds.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f]];
        [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [textView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

        textView.text = cell.textLabel.text;
        textView.delegate = self;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        self.textView = textView;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

I want to set the `textView.text` right where the `cell.textlabel.text` was, but it is a little bit further left and up then the cell text was before. How can I set the cell's text alignment and/or text offset to the UITextView so the text will be at the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourUITextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0); // Mess around with these values
```

Or...

Set the frame of your textView

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 10, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that almost did the trick. I could get the right vertical alignment with it but no matter which values I try for left or right it doesn't make a difference. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you trying to move the text to the right slightly from the left side of the view?

Comment: yes i do. I don't want to change the size of the frame, because that would mess up my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return value :/

Comment: How would changing the size of the frame of an object contained within your cell mess up the height for row at indexpath? I think you are confusing the cell itself for it's contents. Set the size of the cell directly and it doesn't matter what the size of the objects frame is inside of it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a UIView to the contentView so you can assign it's height properly and then adding a subview for the textView? I need to hear exactly the behavior you are expecting in order to provide an accurate solution. The content view assures proper alignment when toggling in and out of editing mode so adding a UIView directly to this and then a textView into the UIView should solve your issue. Unless there is some other behavior you are expecting.

Comment: I would have to change the `textView.frame.height`, too. Else the text would appear a little bit more up then the `cell.textlabel.text`. I'm calculating the height of the cell according to the textViews height while the user is typing, so the textView's height must be equal to the cell's height.

Comment: Aren't you trying to replace the textLabel?

Comment: also i don't set the editing mode for the UITableView. I just add a UITextView as contentView as soon as the user long pressed a cell

Comment: You need to create a new UITableViewCell from the sounds of it. Create a new class of UITableViewCell and use that instead. That way you can add any objects you wish into that cell and forget about the default UITableViewCell's label property.

Comment: but in this way i have custom UITextViewCells which have UITextViews instead of textlabels. I just wanted to add textviews to cells which the user renames using a long press gesture.

Comment: Look at the following link and specifically the cellForRowAtIndexPath. You can create any custom cell you wish and completely forget about the label property of a default tableviewcell

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: Correct, you do not need UILabels at all on the cell, you are wanting only UITextViews. By subclassing UITableViewCell and using that in your cellForRowAndIndex method you can customize it however you like.

Comment: This should shed some light on the issue. http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/customizing.html

Comment: ok, new problem.  I have created a custom cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Now the height of the cell is set correctly but the contentview doesn't adept the size of the cell... for clarity: ![my app](http://i.imgur.com/prmLm.png).  I'm done for today, my brain hurts... i will post a detailed description tomorrow -.-

Comment: I just solved it using `[self.textView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];`  Now everything works just fine :-)